# Run service under AD account

Tags: active-directory, service, user-permissions

I am trying to run a custom service (made in visual studio) on a networked applications server that has been joined to a domain. I would like the service to run under a very specific account (Service_ServiceName) for security reasons.

I have created the domain account and granted it the log in as a service right but the service fails to start with the message "The [Service name] on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not used by other services or programs".

When the service is started under local system it loads correctly. If I grant the user admin rights it starts, however (again for security reasons) I don't want the service to run under an administrator account. Is there a specific right that I need to grant to allow this service to run?

Comment: Does the service account have access to application folders/files?

Comment: Yes. The application (service) is installed in C:\Program Files and the service user has access to that specific directory.

Comment: Grab a copy of process monitor and keep trying to run the application/service it will highlight any access issues

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4115328/5601000). The application was trying to listen on a port for inbound https connections. A standard user doesn't have permissions to open an listen on a port. The following command can be executed to allow a single standard user to listen on a local port:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:80/MyUri user=DOMAIN\user
```